How do we assign priority to groups while assigning R-S configuration when chiral carbon is in a ring?
I am having quit a bit of trouble in assigning priority number 3 and 4 are the groups repeat themselves.
I would like help in how one can open this chain to do similar question in future also.

This is the solution that was given, if it is correct do explain how and tell me an method to solve similar question.
My solution: was to distinguish between 3 and 4 was to see which chain was more complex, this way the Ans I got was R but clearly in solution its given S.

Take a look here.

Imgur is no longer hosting media. I have replaced the Imgur link with the picture.

Your mistake was probably this: when the path around the ring returned to the original carbon atom, you kept going for another round making that path longer and higher raking than the ligand path.
That is wrong. As the pictured diagram* shows, when you return to the original atom in a cyclic path you go no farther.  You have to treat that original atom as an endpoint with no more substituents, not even hydrogen atoms or electron pairs. The ligand path, outside the ring, does have hydrogen atoms attached to the carbon in the fifth position, and by that margin is given the higher rank.
*Which should be reproduced in the body of the problem statement, not a separate image
